# How to rotate a div back-and-forth a set number of times with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I have used some J-Query to rotate a div using the rotate plug-in. Problem is that it is continuously rotating, whereas I need to to simply rotate 5 times and then stop. Here is my code so far:

Plug In:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var rotation = function (){
$("#pencil").rotate({
  angle:0, 
  animateTo:2,
  duration:200,
  callback: rotationBack
});
}
var rotationBack = function() {
$("#pencil").rotate({
  angle:0, 
  animateTo:-2,
  duration:200,
  callback: rotation
});
}
rotation();
});
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: post your code which is id 'pencil'

Comment: its a simple box div eg.. {width:25%; height:50%; position:absolute;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your code to limit the number or repetitions, so the functions will keep calling each other indefinitely.

There are better ways to implement this, but one that works is:

Store the number of repetitions as a property in `$("#pencil")`'s `data` and decrement it as necessary.

Jquery can store data a data object in the DOM element, using the following interface:

```
el.data('key', val); //stores value in key
el.data('key'); //retrieve key's value


var rotation = function (times) {
    var el = $("#pencil");
    if(typeof times == 'number'){
        el.data('repeatRotation',times);
    } else {
        times = el.data('repeatRotation')-1;
        el.data('repeatRotation',times);
    }

    if(times > 0){
        $("#pencil").rotate({
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Just call it with:

```
rotation(5);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/zMZpy/).

Comment: Hi MAsterAM - please could you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: Awsome - thanks a lot, works perfectly. Greatful for the help.